# ionic.config.json e/ou $ionicCloudProvider.init

Tags: ionic, push-notification

Qual a diferença entre **$ionicCloudProvider.init** e **ionic.config.json**.

Por exemplo:
Ao configurar Push, pesquisando, há programadores que inserem o "app_id" e "sender_id" no **$ionicCloudProvider.init**, já outros programadores inserem essas informações no **ionic.confi.json**.

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre os 2 e se é realmente necessário inserir em ambos.